# select rows with conditions in sql

Tags: sql, db2

Each concactentation of visid, custid and value might have BOTH "detail" and "confirm" or only "detail".
If it has only "detail", that rows should not be retrieved, else i have to find the difference between datetimes
when combination of visid, custid and value have both "Detail" and "Confirm"

```
visid     custid    value     datetime                value1
123       456       11        2017-03-01 12:34:11     Detail
123       456       11        2017-03-01 12:36:11     confirm
567       342       56        2017-03-01 12:45:11     Detail
567       342       56        2017-03-01 12:46:11     confirm
411       124       78        2017-03-01 12:34:11     Detail

Output:
visid     custid    value     datetime            
123       456       11        00:02:00 (12:36:11 - 12:34:11)
567       342       56        00:01:00 (12:46:11 - 12:45:11)
```

Note: Since last row with 411, 124 and 78 does not have confirm, that row has to be eliminated.

Query I tried:

```
  select visid, custid, value, concat(visid, custid, value) as session, datetime
  from table1
  where datetime between "2017-05-01 00:00:00" and "2017-05-02 00:00:00"
  and value1 in  ('Detail','Confirm')
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datetime` functions are database specific.  In your case, a self-join is a simple approach:

```
select td.visid, fd.custid, td.value, concat(visid, custid, value) as session,
       (tc.datetime - td.datetime) as diff
from table1 td join
     table1 tc
     on td.visid = tc.visid and  td.custid = tc.custid and td.value = tc.value and
        td.value1 = 'Detail' and tc.value1 = 'Confirm';
```

This uses subtraction for the difference.  The exact function depends on the database.